# Lower bound on the minimum eigenvalue of a positive definite matrix using an upperbound on its offdiagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix that has the following properties

1. All of its elements are nonnegative
2. It has 1's along its main diagonal
3. There is an upperbound $0<r<1$ on all of its off-diagonal elements.

Is there a way to lower bound the minimum eigenvalue of this matrix in terms of $r$?

The obvious thing to try is to "raise" all the off-diagonal elements up to $r$, but I could not prove that the resulting matrix would have a smaller minimum eigenvalue than the original matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $r$ is sufficiently, small, then the following argument can be made using either the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) or the [$\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms).  In either case, we obtain the same bound.  One argument is as follows:

Let $M = A - I$.  We note that
$$
\|M\|_\infty = \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} \sum_{j=1}^n |m_{ij}| \leq (n-1)r
$$
Thus, if we have $r < n-1$, then we have the bound
$$
\lambda_{min}(A) = \lambda_{min}(I + M) = \min\{1 + \lambda_i(M): i = 1,\dots,n\} \geq 1 - \|M\|_\infty = 1 - (n-1)r
$$
When $r \geq n-1$, this bound tells us nothing useful.